# Convert Interval type to string in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to write a Spark dataframe to file, but I don't like the format of my column containing an interval:

> INTERVAL '0 01:02:10.237' DAY TO SECOND

I would rather have:

> 01:02:10.237

How can I format/cast the column to return my preferred format as a string.
The column is of type

`interval day to second (nullable = true)`

The `date_format` function unfortunately requires a timestamp type.

Comment: would cast as string and substring work?

Comment: Yes, I guess, regexing on the quotes and using that would work. However it always feels a little 'unclean' extracting information from a string. I am suprised that there isn't an official function for that (that I know of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex

```
df.show()

+-----------------------------------+
|duration                           |
+-----------------------------------+
|INTERVAL '0 06:18:05' DAY TO SECOND|
+-----------------------------------+

df.withColumn('duration_new', regexp_extract('duration','\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}',0)).show(truncate=False)

+-----------------------------------+------------+
|duration                           |duration_new|
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|INTERVAL '0 06:18:05' DAY TO SECOND|06:18:05    |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a regex (imo you shouldn't), the separate interval components can be extracted and then formatted as needed.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.range(2)
df = df.withColumn(
    'interval_col', F.expr("INTERVAL '0 01:02:10.237' DAY TO SECOND")
)

formatted = F.format_string(
    '%02d:%02d:%02.3f',
    F.expr('EXTRACT(HOUR FROM interval_col)'),
    F.expr('EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM interval_col)'),
    F.expr('EXTRACT(SECOND FROM interval_col)').cast('double'),
)
df.select(
    'interval_col',
    formatted.alias('formatted')
).show(10, False)

# +---------------------------------------+------------+
# |interval_col                           |formatted   |
# +---------------------------------------+------------+
# |INTERVAL '0 01:02:10.237' DAY TO SECOND|01:02:10.237|
# |INTERVAL '0 01:02:10.237' DAY TO SECOND|01:02:10.237|
# +---------------------------------------+------------+
```